# Mongoose - Check for a value between two numbers

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a mongoose document that contains two ages. The ***minimum age*** to go to the attraction and the ***maximum one***.

I need to query my database to get all attractions between 0 and 2 years old.

But this won't work :

```
"ageMin": {
  "$lte": 2
},
"ageMax": {
  "$gte": 0
},
```

Because most of my attraction are between 0 and 99.

To help you visualise i made an example:

```
attractionOne: {
  name: "Deadly Looping",
  ageMin: 12,
  ageMax: 99
}
attractionTwo: {
  name: "Easy Ladybug",
  ageMin: 0,
  ageMax: 12
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Any sample data would help to have an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to match if those ranges are overlapping with `0-2` range then you're close, just need to check if `0-2` range is between `min` and `max` age. Try:

```
db.attractions.find({ ageMin: { $lte: 0 }, ageMax: { $gte: 2 } })
```